# Is there a better way to handle my MySQL database tables?

Tags: mysql, database

My website allows people to create quizzes. Each quiz contains up to 20 questions and each question contains up to 5 answers. I have a database table for quizzes, questions and answers. This means one quiz can have 121 rows. Is there a better way of handling this such as having quiz answers in a separate column in the questions table?

Comment: Can you share your table schema? I'm not sure how you're getting 131 rows per a single quiz as 20 * 5 is only 100, and it's not clear from your post how the db is set up.

Comment: "Is there a better way of handling this such as having quiz answers in a separate column in the questions table?" -> You don't want to covert the rows into columns trust me you will run into trouble later on.

Comment: As a basic general rule: if A can have more than one B, then A and B should be separate tables. _Your corrected row count indicates you are handling it appropriately._

Comment: @citrusy he's counting 100 answer rows + 20 question rows + 1 quiz row.

Comment: You should have 3 tables: `quizzes`, `questions`, and `answers`. `questions` has a foreign key to `quizzes`, `answers` has a foreign key to `questions`.

Comment: Read a tutorial on database normalization.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. I asked this question as I am thinking what if I have 10000 quizzes, all of a sudden that is 1 Million rows and this I may run into performance issues. As long as what I have is the most effective option, that is fine.

Comment: Normalization helps with performance as well as learning general good database design practices. I strongly recommend taking @Barmar's advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the default *InnoDB* engine - one row adds an overhead of something like 20 bytes. That are about 20 MB for one million rows, which is pretty nothing for modern hardware, if organized and indexed well. You should be fine even if you use a smartphone as server.

You should however use at least one table per entity. Quizzes, questions and answers are different entities - so you should have at least three tables, which are linked by foreign keys.

Here's an example of a normalized schema:

```
create table quizzes(
    quiz_id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    title varchar(255)
);

create table questions (
    question_id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    quiz_id int unsigned not null
    title varchar(255),
    foreign key (quiz_id) references quizzes(quiz_id)
);

create table answers (
    answer_id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    question_id int unsigned not null
    title varchar(255),
    foreign key (question_id) references questions(question_id)
);
```